# No such file or directory; But the file does exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualenv, bioinformatics, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to run a Binoinformatics program, DistMap on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (x86_64). I am getting the error `No such file or directory`. But the file do exist in the required location. 
I have used this program before and it ran perfectly fine. Yesterday I installed virtualenv-burrito for some other program, Seal. Since then I haven't been able to run DistMap.

I know there have been many posts regarding this error all over the internet. But the solution seems to be the same for all the posts.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

This solution is for running 32-bit application on 64-bit machines. But since Distmap worked before without any problem I dont think that is the problem. Still, I installed ia32-libs; just for the sake of it but no use.

I am sure the problem is virtualenv-burrito. So I uninstalled it from my machine (Deleted .virtualenv and .virtualburrito folders. Since that's the only way i found for uninstalling virtualenv-burrito on the internet). Still my application is not running.

How can I bring my system to default as in to the previous state of virtualenv-burrito installation?

I hope I will get some good suggestions. I have been struggling for sometime now.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind showing the exact command-line you use to invoke DistMap?

Comment: Distmap manual can be accessed from [here](http://code.google.com/p/distmap/wiki/Manual). I executed DistMap using `./distmap --reference-fasta /mnt/shared/data/WholeGenomeFasta/genome.fa --input "/mnt/shared/data/synthetic_sample1.fq,/mnt/shared/data/synthetic_sample2.fq" --mapper bowtie2 --mapper-path /home/hadoop/bowtie2-2.0.6/bowtie2 --picard-mergesamfiles-jar /home/hadoop/picard-tools-1.100/MergeSamFiles.jar --picard-sortsam-jar /home/hadoop/picard-tools-1.100/SortSam.jar --output /mnt/shared/bowtie2 --hadoop-home /home/hadoop/hadoop`

Comment: Error I have been getting is this `Copy failed: No such file or directory at /home/hadoop/DistMap_v1.0/bin/GenomeIndex.pm line 282.` the file exists in the mentioned location.

Comment: I don't think it's complaining about `GenomeIndex.pm`.  It's saying that on line 282 of that file, it's failing to copy a file.  Perhaps the file it's trying to copy does not exist, or the destination cannot be accessed.

Comment: Ohk. Do you have any idea why is that happening, as it was working perfectly fine a few days ago. Anything to do with virtualenv?

Comment: Sorry, not sure.  Never used hadoop, distmap, or virtualenv!  I would  look at the source code near that error in `GenomeIndex.pm` and see what it's trying to do, then work backwards from there.  You could modify it to output more information if you're not sure.  Can you read Perl code?

Comment: I cant read distmap file. but I dont really understand how to proceed further..

Comment: Why can't you read it?  Is it not a text file?  I'm talking about `GenomeIndex.pm`, not `distmap`.

Comment: Oh sorry..I can read GenomeIndex.pm

Comment: Maybe using a tool like strace or ltrace will give you a hint where the app tries to open the file. THough the output of these commands is lengthy.